# Requesting facebook permissions on tab page in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having one facebook pagetab application and I am stuck in following situation

I need to check if user login or not

> if not then redirect to login url with `user_likes,publish_actions,email` permissions

and also user has liked page or not.

> if not liked then show the like gate

Now in above I am stuck following error which I am getting in FB pagetab (`iFRAM`)

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=839424369402407&redire…c8682d9a9fb5b&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.9&scope=email%2Cuser_likes%2Cpublish_actions' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Now I am think to implement the flow with JS sdk, get the access token and then pass it to php code using ajax call

Is there any better way to solve this situation??

here is the code

```
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getCode());
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getCode());
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
}
if($_GET['error']=="access_denied"){
    header("location:/login/");
    exit;
}else if (isset($session) || (isset($_SESSION['fb_user_session_access_token'])) && !empty($_SESSION['fb_user_session_access_token'])) {
    if(isset($session))
        $_SESSION['fb_user_session_access_token'] = $session->getToken();
    else{
        $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_user_session_access_token'];
        $session = new FacebookSession($access_token);
    }

    try {
        $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me'
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
        $email =  $user_profile->getProperty('email');
        $name =  $user_profile->getProperty('name');
        $fb_id =  $user_profile->getProperty('id');
        $query = mysql_query("select id, email from ntuc_users where email = '$email'");
        $user_found = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if(!$user_found){
        //code deleted
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        error_log($e->getCode());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        //if token get expired
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'));
        header("location:".$loginUrl);
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'));
  header("location:".$loginUrl);
  exit;
}
```

thanks in advanced

Comment: In regards to the like-gate, stop what you are doing right now. This is going to be against the Platform Policy as of November 5, 2014

Comment: @BjörnKaiser Can you please explain `what is wrong`??

Comment: First of all, what you are building (like gated app) is against the Facebook Platform Policy, and second: you will need to submit the user_likes and publish_actions permission for approval, at least user_likes will not be approved for your app because of the above stated reason. This is more an FYI than a solution to your problem, but that is what comments are for and I just want to save you some work ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days research, I got this.. here is the flow which I have implemented for my app

@BjörnKaiser mentioned Facebook policy doesn't support LIKEGATE anymore.. and its true ..

## So I have go through FB policy and got the following ans

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions. Effective November 5th, 2014, you may no longer incentivize people to like your app's Page

[**FB POLICY**](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse)
However as ref. to above information, i tried to implement likegate flow but FB hardluck with FB APP review team

## But I got one more ref. from the review team

> Please note that using "user_likes" to check if someone has liked your Facebook use case is not approvable. User_likes provides information to all of a person's likes, and the entirety of this data should be used to enhance the app experience. If you need to determine who has already liked your page, please use signed requests for Page Tab apps.

[**FB USER LIKE POLICY**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#user-likes)

Using `signed requests`, at least for pagetab it works like a charm :).. but for mobile website, I have removed the it

Here is the code:

```
        if( isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']) )
        {
            $user_data = $this->parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request']);
            $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_user_session_access_token'];
        }
        if( (isset($user_data['page']["liked"]) && !empty($user_data['page']["liked"]) && $user_data['page']["liked"]) || $this->deviceType != "computer")//no like gate for mobile
        {
            //my code ...
        }


private function parse_signed_request($signed_request) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    $secret = FB_APP_SECRET; // Use your app secret here

    // decode the data
    $sig = $this->base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode($this->base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    // confirm the signature
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        $this->log->write('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

private function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

I hope it helps someone else...